# List of Tuples into a Dictionary -- Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples and I have converted them into a dictionary, but I would like to have the value be the "book name" be the key and the value be the "author name".
this is my list of tuples:

```
books=[('Douglas Adams', "The Hitchhiker"), ('Richard Adams', 'Watership'),('Richard Adams', 'ship'), ('Mitch Albom', 'The Five People'), ('Laurie Anderson', 'Speak'), ('Maya Angelou', 'Caged Bird Sings')]
```

How I converted it to a dictionary:

```
oneOfEachBook = dict(books) 
print(oneOfEachBook)
```

my output:

```
{'Douglas Adams': 'The Hitchhiker', 'Richard Adams': 'ship', 'Mitch Albom': 'The Five People', 'Laurie Anderson': 'Speak', 'Maya Angelou': 'Caged Bird Sings'}
```

as you can see my books by Richard Adams are allowing one of the books. I understand that it is skipping the first but I do not know what to do to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: That's because ```dict``` can not have duplicate keys. Try storing multiple books for each author inside a list for that author/

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to have lists as values of the dictionary. Therefore you can have mode book names associated with the author:

```
books = [
    ("Douglas Adams", "The Hitchhiker"),
    ("Richard Adams", "Watership"),
    ("Richard Adams", "ship"),
    ("Mitch Albom", "The Five People"),
    ("Laurie Anderson", "Speak"),
    ("Maya Angelou", "Caged Bird Sings"),
]

out = {}
for author, title in books:
    out.setdefault(author, []).append(title)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Douglas Adams': ['The Hitchhiker'], 'Richard Adams': ['Watership', 'ship'], 'Mitch Albom': ['The Five People'], 'Laurie Anderson': ['Speak'], 'Maya Angelou': ['Caged Bird Sings']}
```